# How to inline outlook email template text (nowrap works in browser but not working in outlook app)?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have tried with multiple solution like using nowrap attribute and wordspace:nowrap csss for outlook email template.

This work very fine when email opens in browser but if email open in outlook the email text breaks by space and goes to next line.

Anyone know the work around of css for outlook like nowrap which we use in browser.

Note: I am using table structure and adding inline css for html template.

Any suggetion is very thankful.

Comment: `<pre>` might help with your issue. You can keep it as the last available option if nothing else works out.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reply. I have tried <pre> as well it is not working in my case.